# Symettric Dependece

Tags: java, tomcat, symmetricds

Hello i am running Symetric 3.9 with TomEE Plume i deploy the war and in the deploy i have this error in the log:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.hsqldb.HsqlDbFunctions org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.hsqldb.HsqlDbFunctions in statement [CREATE FUNCTION sym_base_64_encode(binaryData BINARY)                                                                                                                                                      RETURNS VARCHAR(1000000)                                                                                                                                     NO SQL                                                                                                                                                       LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA                                                                                                                           EXTERNAL NAME                                                                                                                                                 'CLASSPATH:org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.hsqldb.HsqlDbFunctions.encodeBase64'                                                                                  ]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate$5.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:374)
    at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate$5.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:342)
    at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:491)
    ... 14 more
```

I know that is for an library or something in the classpath that i miss, but i dont know in what classpath or what library

Comment: It's there on the class part the jar symmetric-db-3.9.jar?

Comment: no, i dont know how to do that.... please say to me

Comment: I am curious about that too. The only file I have is `symmetric-wrapper.jar` adding of which on the CP does not help.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using HSQLDB and running the database in a process that is independent of the SymmetricDS process.  When you do so, you need to include the symmetric-client jar file on the classpath of the HSQLDB server so it has access to Java functions and triggers.

Comment: Yes i am using Hsqldb as an independent procces, i know that te symettric-client jar is in the web lib but i dont know to put in in the Hsqldb server classpath, can you say to me please

Comment: How are you starting HSQLDB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this JAR on the HSQLDB's classpath:

`symmetric-server-3.9.8/web/WEB-INF/lib/symmetric-client-3.9.8.jar`